# Can't track a tag badge in my profile

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, badges, user-profile

When I go to the tag badge tracker in my profile, it says that I already have the [skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim) gold tag badge, and I am unable to select it to be tracked.

[image: screenshot]

However, when I go to the [badges section of my profile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/4797/galacticninja?tab=badges), it says that I still don't have that badge.

Might this be a bug? How do I select the [skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim) gold tag badge for tracking?

Comment: Previously on [metase]: [Tracked tag badge incorrectly shown as earned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254396/tracked-tag-badge-incorrectly-shown-as-earned)

Comment: [This Meta Stack Exchange issue is the same issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254395/tag-badges-are-being-awarded-incorrectly)

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Comment: @JarrodDixon It seems to be working fine now. I am now able to track the [skyrim] gold tag badge.